# How to hide exoplayer buffer indicator in progress bar (seekbar)?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using exoplayer to play offline videos, I don't want to show the buffer indicator in the progress bar as it makes no sense. I tried app:show_buffering="never", it didn't work.
I am using latest exoplayer version as of date, i.e., 2.11.8

[ I don't know what to call that, few refer to that as secondary progress.]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the actual solution for this, but the below workaround worked for me.

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        app:unplayed_color="@color/grey"
        app:buffered_color="@color/grey"/>
```

Setting both unplayed_color and buffered_color to same color removes that difference between buffered indicator, which is not needed.